# Fedora: Caps-lock LED only works after login?

Tags: fedora, laptop

I have a Dell Inspiron 3542 laptop with Fedora installed fine. However, the caps-lock LED only works after I've entered my password (the disk is encrypted with [LUKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup)).

How could I make the caps-lock LED additionally work before entering the password?

I have tried editing `/etc/modprobe.conf`, and `make mkinitrd` but neither of these resulted in the caps-lock LED working.

Fedora is 27,the latest.

On modprobe.conf i put the module list

```
usbcore
uchi-hcd
ehci-hcd
hid
hid-generic
usbhid
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate with what version of Fedora you are using, and what specific changes you made to the `modprobe.conf` file?

Comment: yes,i will edit the message now